# typescript generic that alters one attribute of a given type

Tags: typescript, generics

i want to create a generic that alters one attribute of a given type, something like:

`type Person = { name: string, age: number }`

in a way that `AlterAttribute<Person, 'age', string>`
returns this type:

`type Person = { name: string, age: string }`

i tried this

`export type AlterAttribute<T, K extends keyof T, P> = Omit<T, K> & { [M in keyof K]: P }`

but it doesn't work as expected:

`const person: AlterAttribute<Person, 'age', number> = { name: 'Joe', age: 10 };`

`Type '{ name: string; age: number; }' is not assignable to type 'AlterAttribute<Person, "age", number>'. Type '{ name: string; age: number; }' is not assignable to type '"age"'.`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Is your question "why didn't my attempt work" or "what is the best way to write this"?  If it's the former then the only problem is that you're using `keyof K` (which doesn't make sense, that's "the keys of the keys") and should just be `K`.   If it's the latter then I'd offer something like `type AlterAttribute<T, K extends keyof T, V> = { [P in keyof T]: P extends K ? V : T[K] }`.  Please [edit] the question to clarify which of those is your primary question and then we can answer accordingly.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You should define it as

```
type AlterAttribute<T, K extends keyof T, P> = Omit<T, K> & { [M in K]: P }
```

`K` is the union type, which should be the key of the "new" object, hence `[M in K]`

[TS Playgound](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAChBOBnA9gOygXigbyqghgLYQBcUiw8AlqgOYA0U+tp5lNtUAvgFA8QAPMMnjAooSFACCAG2AIpwdgCMArvIA8AFUYBpKIPmoAJoigBrCCGQAzKDtgA+TFADyhKsG17nAMhxQANoAslA0ULoAumQw3HwAxmgUUJBIaGSy8vCKKuoQGnBpqIwA5MwQJYyoqoTKCM5YuATEZCUAUsgVjOVkAIwADNwA3DxAA)